# How to make vim pathogen to reload plugins?

Tags: vim, plugins, reload, pathogen

Is it possible to make vim to reload pathogen plugins without restarting vim?
I have opened vim with many files, then I add plugin to:

*~/.vim/bundle*
Since now I'd like to force vim to use the new plugin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pathogen just manipulates the `'runtimepath'` option; the situation with plugin reloads is therefore the same as with the plain default plugin structure. (Other plugin managers may offer this kind of reload / dynamic enable functionality; I suppose you want to stick with Pathogen.)

To retroactively enable a plugin in a running Vim session, you need to `:source` all (usually that's only one) *plugin* scripts that have been added. For a plugin named `foobar`, that would be:

```
:source ~/.vim/bundle/foobar/plugin/foobar.vim
```

If you can get Pathogen to re-initialize the `'runtimepath'` (or augment it yourself via `:set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/foobar`), you can also use the shorter

```
:runtime plugin/foobar.vim
```

Comment: I tried this after installing matchit but it didn't work. I sourced the .vim file in the plugin dir and executed the runtime command. Not sure what I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a modern version of vim, you can use its built-in package manager, which has a convenient function to reload all plugins:

```
:packloadall
```

http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Apackloadall

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat before util I find an awesome plugin(**[vim-reload](https://github.com/xolox/vim-reload.git)**) to do these stuffs automatic in an amazing way.You should have a shot at this plugin.